# change attribute value using selenuim python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript

I am try to change non input attribute value in Firefox frame in the format:

```
 <div id='100' class='abc'>
<p> hello </p>
</div>
<div id='200' class='abc'>
<p> hello 2 </p>
</div>
…..
```

I want to change **hello 2** to **welcome** 
I try this code but it does not work

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0].text='welcome';");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your locator would fetch the first div, of *id* = 100.

Try the following:

```
document.querySelector('#200 p').innerText='welcome';
```

Comment: thanks it works ,

Comment: what if I want to use class name 'abc'??

Comment: `document.querySelector(".abc p")`